# Can i make a Text to an input radio with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have to radio button and i want to make for each one a text value, some think like yes and no.

```
<input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad1" class="tab1" checked="checked"/> 
<input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad2" class="tab2"/>
```

I want to khnow if i can just with CSS make a text for these radios?

like :

```
.tab1{
   content:'Yes';
}
.tab2{
   content:'No';
}
```

Comment: That's what labels are for....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inputs aren't supposed to have pseudo-elements per the W3C spec although some browsers have decided to implement them anyway.

Ideally you should use **actual** text in a `label` but if you chose not to you can use a label anyway and put the pseudo-element on that.

```css
.tab1 + label:before {
  content: 'Yes';
  display: inline-block;
}
.tab2 +label:before {
  content: 'No';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad1" class="tab1" checked="checked" />
<label for="rad1"></label>
<input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad2" class="tab2" />
<label for="rad2"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.tab1:after{
  content: 'Yes';
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
.tab2:after{
  content: 'No';
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avGdwB (note the line break in the HTML).

Comment: Hmm, that's a bugger. I know you're meant to answer the question and not give personal opinions, but while it's possible, you're *far* better just putting the text into the HTML.

Comment: That's because the W3C spec says it shouldn't. - Question a little old but still on point - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-the-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field

Answer (score 1):

Use :after for content property.

HTML

```
<label id="rad1" class="tab1">
  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" checked="checked"/>
</label>
<label id="rad2" class="tab2"> 
  <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1"/>
</label>
```

CSS

```
.tab1:before{
  content:'Yes';
}
.tab2:before{
  content:'No';
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ilyabogdanov/zvqh0t1q/)